# Compilation stops a 70% while lazily loading an Angular Module

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement lazy loading in my application. But compilation stops at 70% after adding the below snippet.

>

```
 {
    path: 'sandbox',
    resolve: { lang: LocaleService },
    loadChildren: './SANDBOX/sandbox.module#SandBoxModule'
  },
```

Earlier I was using this:

```
{
    path: 'sandbox',
    resolve: { lang: LocaleService },
    loadChildren: ()=>SandBoxModule
  }
```

[image: Have added a screenshot of compilation getting stuck]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to resolve it. Some problem with multiple version of webpack. Removed the one in package.json and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using lazyloading module concept of angular.

**resolve: { lang: LocaleService }**

Instead of using resolve with module load, you need to use this resolve with load component. Define resolve inside your route file of this module  'SandBoxModule' and then try to run.

Comment: Thanks, @Mohit. I tried that as well but still the same thing.

Comment: can you please try to build after removing resolve line?